# Expand graph over twocolumns on titlepage

Tags: graphics, captions, two-column, includegraphics

I am using the (very outdated) documentclass `asme2ej`, which produces two-column academic journal documents.

My problem is as follows: 
**I want to print my title, switch to onecolumn style and add an abstract plus one graph on the very same first page.**

Below you find my current code, which is the closest I got. However, gives me the error:

*Package caption Error: No float type 'MyFigure.png' defined. ]*

I experimented with `\usepackage{graphicx}`, but it seems to not work properly in this outdated environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\section*{Executive Summary}

My Summary.

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\rule{0.75\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{MyFigure.png}{MyCaption}\label{fig:dummy}
\end{minipage}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}

]
```

This is the output I get (when changing *MyFigure.png* to *figure* to compile it).

[image]

Any help how to obtain my graph here would be highly appreciated. I am not sure whether the problem lies in the package I am using or in how I load the graph over `captionof{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see, if the following solution work for you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Some title}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\maketitle
\section*{Executive Summary}
My Summary.

{\lipsum[66]

 \lipsum[77]}

\begin{center}
{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
\captionof{figure}{MyCaption}\label{fig:dummy}
\end{center}
]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

as you can notice, i remove package `multicol` (it is not clear, why you need it, you declare that your document is `twocolumn`) and `epsfig`, which is with recent LaTeX not necessary anymore.

Comment: I already handed my report in, but not being able to solve the problem was really a minor annoyance. Your solution works perfectly. Apparently the use of `multicol` was causing the problems. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `\captionof` should be the type of float, in your case `figure`. To insert the image, replace the black dummy rectangle width `\includegraphics{example-image}` (replace `example-image` with the filename of your image)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2ej}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\section*{Executive Summary}

My Summary.

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image}}
\captionof{figure}{MyCaption}\label{fig:dummy}
\end{minipage}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}

]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @jackfrost, thank you very much. This solution indeed displays the imagine finally. However, I am not able to scale it. As soon as I add option to `\includegraphics`, such as `\includegraphics[width=0.30/textwidth]{MyFigure.png}` I get the error: **Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }. \includegraphics[width=0.30/textwidth]**. I do not know if packages interfer. I never had such troubles to include a picture properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @XsLiar I modified the code to include the width